# Github pages DNS settings issue

Tags: git, github, dns, jekyll, github-pages

### Background / Goal

- I have a Github repository with Jekyll at http://seankilleen.github.io
- I have the http://SeanKilleen.com domain name that I'd like to forward to the Github pages.
- I am using NameCheap as my DNS provider.

### The Problem

No matter what I do, I seem to see the following error message in an e-mail:

[image: Github error e-mail]

And I see the following on the actual page:

[image: Github error page]

What am I doing wrong?

### Notes on my Setup

- I have a CNAME file in my repository with the contents set to `seankilleen.com`
- CNAME file links:

  - [In its current state](https://github.com/SeanKilleen/seankilleen.github.io/blob/master/CNAME)
  - [At the point when I wrote this question](https://github.com/SeanKilleen/seankilleen.github.io/commit/e621981beed249e43e836ee69c46d27aebb8302b)
- I have tried my DNS setup in the following configurations:

  - A records for `@` pointing to `192.30.252.153` and `192.30.252.154` respectively, with a `www` record pointing to `seankilleen.github.io.`
  - both `@` and `www` entries with CNAME records to `seankilleen.github.io`
  - Various combinations of the two
- This is how my DNS setup currently looks:
  [image: Current DNS setup]
- I am pushing changes in my repository to the `master` branch.
- I had also tried renaming my repository to `SeanKilleen.com` and using a `gh-pages` branch, but that didn't change the result so I renamed the repo back and removed the `gh-pages` branch.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Post your CNAME file somewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/SeanKilleen/seankilleen.github.io/blob/master/CNAME is where it is in the repo. I'll update the question too. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I had already tried that, with A records to both of the IPs. Same exact result. Will try again now for good measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try A records to seankilleen.github.io

Comment: When doing this, I receive an error: `INVALID_IP: 'seankilleen.github.io.' is not valid IP for A record. (host name: @)`

Comment: I have updated the screenshot in the question to reflect the current DNS settings, which include two A records for `@` pointing to the Github IPs and a CNAME record for `www` pointing to `seankilleen.github.io`. Still the same result.

Comment: It works now. DNS propogation takes a bit; maybe we were checking too soon to see changes reflected?

Comment: I had waited a while, but between all the changes, etc. it's still possible that we just needed some extra propagation time. Thanks for trying to jump in on it! Since your answer is technically correct, I'll mark it as such. :) Thanks again

Comment: I don't understand...my DNS provider's input form allows only IP addresses for A records. Am I misunderstanding this answer?